# Как правильно писать? Ждём вас на программе или ждём вас на программу?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно писать? ***С 4 марта ждём вас на программе*** или ***ждём вас на программу***?

Comment: Правильно "Ждем вас (где?) на программе". Есть разговорное выражение "жду вас к себе" или "ждем вас к нам в гости". Наверное можно употребить и "ждем вас к нам на программу".

Answer (score 1):

Правильно будет использовать словосочетание «съемки программы».

Цитата из Нац.корпуса: Есть желание побывать на съемках программы «Кто хочет стать миллионером?» [Оксана ФОМИНА, Мария КИРСАНОВА. 200 читателей «КП» попадут на съемки «Миллионера» // Комсомольская правда, 2004.02.16]

-- В таком случае, ждем Вас на съемки программы, которые состоятся (там-то и тогда-то).

Comment: здесь имеется ввиду не съёмка программы, а проведение праздничной программы в музее